# My Social Security Card Number

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, calculation-puzzle

I have forgotten my social security card number. All I remember is that it is the largest integer with the property that the block of any two of its digits that are adjacent is either a two-digit prime number or a two-digit perfect square, and that these are all different.

What is it?

Comment: That's a very interesting thing to remember about your social security card number ...

Comment: Do we know how many digits is the number?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: No, I cannot remember that either. Quite a few...

Comment: Do the 2-digit blocks overlap? Can a 2-digit number have a leading 0?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes and yes.

Comment: For no particular reason... What is your mother's maiden name and what was the name of your first/current/favorite pet? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 253797364171613119

#### Proof:

> We cannot use zeros; a two digit number ending in zero is not prime and 00 is the only square, so zeros can only appear at the beginning and can therefore be ignored.
>
>  Let's list the squares we can use: 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81
>  and the primes: 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97

It's a bit like:

> domino: to maximize the total number, we first need to maximize the number of pairs we can make.

See the following table:

> `. start end match`
>  `1 5     6   5`
>  `2 3     0   0`
>  `3 3     6   3`
>  `4 4     1   1`
>  `5 2     1   1`
>  `6 3     2   2`
>  `7 3     5   3`
>  `8 3     0   0`
>  `9 1     6   1`

So we can make

> 16 matches, for a 18 digit Social Security Card Number.

In theory, we want

> the largest numbers to appear first, but the only pair ending in 5 is 25.
>  So we start with 25.
>  The next one cannot be 59, because we need the 9 for both 79 and 19; one of them can be at the very end
>  but the other must be somewhere inside the number.
>  So the next one is 53, then 37, then 79, then 97, then 73, then 36.
>  67 won't work, as we've used up all our sevens except for the one needed for 17; so we take 64.
>  We've used up all our nines, sevens and threes except for the one needed for 13; so we take 41.
>  The next one is 17, then 71, then 16, then 61, then 13, then 31, then 11, and finally 19.

Concatenating all the pairs we get the answer:

> **253797364171613119**

Comment: If we actually add two leading zeroes, the properties still hold